# iterating rows in dataframe and adding objects into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a txt file into a dataframe and now trying to iterate over the rows of the pandas dataframe and create a student object for each of the data entries. and eventually, store the student objects in a list "students".

I am a little confused about how to iterate the rows and add students objects to the students list. Can anyone help me creating this list?
thank you

```
students = []
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('students.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

file output

```
 firstname   lastname     status  gpa
0      Mike     Barnes   freshman  4.0
1       Jim  Nickerson  sophomore  3.0
2      Jack    Indabox     junior  2.5
3      Jane        Doe   freshman  1.1
4      Jane     Miller     senior  3.6
5      Mary      Scott     senior  2.7
6      John        Doe     senior  1.0
7     Elvis    Presley  sophomore  1.5
8    Batman      Wayne   freshman  0.5
9      Jack        Pot     junior  2.0
```

Comment: What is a "student object"? Do you have a class called Student?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.iterrows()` function of the dataframe in a loop and access each column in the specific row by `.<name>` to create your instance of a student class:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    row.firstname
    row.lastname
    row.status
    row.gpa
```

Comment: Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: @tyler how would you vectorise object creation based on row data?

Comment: If OP is simply converting rows of a text file to a list of objects, then Pandas is overkill. I would just read the file using `readlines()`.

Comment: thank you all! I used the first solution with student.append to save as a list.